# Sorting Product by names in POS (js)

Tags: javascript, odoo-10, point-of-sale

How do I sort my product names in POS product list?
Here's my code, which says names.sort() is not a function.
In js file

```
for(var i = 0, len = this.product_list.length; i < len; i++)
{
    var product_node = this.render_product(this.product_list[i]);
    var names = this.product_list[i].display_name
    var sorted_names = names.sort();
    console.log('Sorted Names',sorted_names)
}
```

Comment: check console.log(names). Is it really returning an array or not.

Comment: No, it displays me an error as: - "Uncaught TypeError: names.sort is not a function"

Comment: names is not an array try console.log(names) and see the result. That's why you are getting names.sort is not a function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do something like this,

```
var names=[];//array for names
   for(var i = 0, len = this.product_list.length; i < len; i++)
{
    var product_node = this.render_product(this.product_list[i]);
    names.push(this.product_list[i].display_name);//push name in the array
}
names.sort();//sort names
console.log(names);//sorted array
```